# Insert 3 appendices after Bibliography and include them in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

How to insert 3 appendices after Bibliography and include them in the TOC for my thesis

I have no idea as i am beginner in Latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to have the the appendices in your document and in the toc, just write

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\bibliography
\clearpage

\appendix


 \newpage%
 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}% For Alpha numeric number
 \section{First Appendix}
  % Stuff here 
  \section{Second Appendix}
  % Stuff here 
  \section{Third Appendix}
  % Stuff here 

 \end{document}
```